# how to install Basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm a complete novice learning python. I'm trying to install basemap on windows 64 and am having trouble with it.

I've been trying to follow the instructions from https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html, but being the novice that I am, I'm confused about the steps. Can anyone clarify it a little bit? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *confused* about what exactly? What did you try, and what didn't work?

Comment: There is a step by step guideline in the link you provide. I strongly doubt anyone can come up with an even better version of it here. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I followed the instructions but was getting an error. I ended up downloading the file from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ instead and also downloaded Visual Studio to resolve the error, and it worked for me!